# Configure Dynamic Columns from DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating a DataGridView Library, where I am passing DataTable but not displaying all columns rather there is an option to Configure Columns and chose which columns to display on the grid. Here is my function

```
public void ConfigureColumns(DataTable dataTable, params String[] columnNames)
{
  var _dataGridView = new DataGridView();
  var index = 0;
  foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
  {
     var colName = column.ColumnName;
     foreach (var newColumn in from columnName in columnNames
            where columnName == colName
            select new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn {Name = columnName, Visible = true})
     {
          _dataGridView.Columns.Insert(index, newColumn);
           index++;
      }
   }
}
```

I am using foreach twice in this, I was just wondering if there is any way to optimize it, Also how to display the DataRows in this of those columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be optimized, you don't really need the inner foreach loop. Using a more appropriate data structure (e.g. a HashSet) an "if" statement can be enough. Also instead of the Insert method you can use Add, so you don't have to create and maintain an index field.

```
public void ConfigureColumns(DataTable dataTable, params String[] columnNames)
{
    var _dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    HashSet<String> columns = new HashSet<String>(columnNames);

    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        var colName = column.ColumnName;
        if (columns.Contains(colName)) 
        {
            var newColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {Name = columnName, Visible = true};
            _dataGridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

After constructing your grid just call:

```
_dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false; // As you want to display a subset of the columns
_dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Comment: Thanks @tpolyak, I am able to successfully configure the columns, However My data is not displayed in the Grid, I think it is because of mismatch between the columns in the dataTable Column's and the DataGrid View columns.

Comment: Try what's happening if you remove all custom column generating code and autogenerate=false, and just set the datasource of the datagrid. Can you see your datatable in the grid?

Comment: If I remove the code to add custom columns, then the data is visible. I suspect I have to create the datatable again based on only what I have to display..

Comment: Try to change the order of the statements: put AutoGenerateColumns=false and DataSource = dataTable before adding your custom columns.

Comment: Official example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how is solved it.. Showed the columns dynamically and display values in that.

```
public void ConfigureColumns(DataTable dataTable, params String[] columnNames)
{
  var _dataGridView = new DataGridView();
  HashSet<String> columns = new HashSet<String>(columnNames);

  foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
  {
     var colName = column.ColumnName;
     if (columns.Contains(colName)) 
     {
         var newColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {Name = columnName, Visible = true};
    //    _dataGridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
     }
  }

   var newTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnNames);
  _dataGridView.DataSource = newTable;
}
```